# use tree to make sitemap

Tags: firefox, gedit, text, tree

Time For my daily Ubuntu lulz. 
i went to make a site map using "$tree public_html/ > tree.txt"

ok, looks good in gedit. put that in my site..
and all the pipes and dashes are garbage. .. have a look if you like>
http://nanocluster.umeche.maine.edu/tree.txt

I get that this is probably some ascii compliance issue. 
is there a simple fix to get this looking like it does in gedit via firefox?
should I just write a script to embed the tree info into a web-page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make your server to declare the UTF-8 encoding:

[image]

Without UTF-8:

[image]

The configuration depends on your server. You can also change the UTF-8 (Unicode) to ASCII. The results are horrible, but at least are no gibberish.

```
iconv -f utf8 -t iso89 oldfile > newfile
```

Comment: This apears to be exactly what i want. When i try to use it, I get he message: $ iconv -f utf8 -t iso89 tree.txt > tree1.txt
iconv: conversion to `iso89' is not supported. There are so many ooptions in the list, iam not sure what to use....

Comment: @j0h windows-1252, render the characters correctly

Comment: Thank you Braiam, for getting me started in the right direction. after your last bit of help I got this:iconv: illegal input sequence at position 2
which led me to this page that give me the answer I needed. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7688464/iconv-unicode-unknown-input-format